# Simple HTML Dom Can't access 3rd level DIV element

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I am trying to display the value 2.11 by using the attribute of data-gamename="1x2" from the third DIV, The code below are from original source.

```
<div class="games">==$0 
  <div class="wrap"> 
<div class="outcome" onclick="addBet(this)" id="outcome-225162629" data-gameid="61158022" data-outcomeid="225162629" data-gamename="1X2" data-eventname="Benevento Calcio - Carpi FC" data-eventcodeid="137" data-gamename="1X2">2.11</div>
```

From the above code if i want retrieve values of  it will work good and if i want to retrieve values from  it will work good too and make to make a record this second div is inside the first div of  there it come another one inside the second div of  it is called  My problem start here if i want to retrieve data from lets say  it will work like charm but if i change the attribute lets say  like in example above it will not work, it just display nothing i tried to solve with no lucky , As the code look above can any one help me where am wrong?

This is the code for retrieve the value

```
<?php 
include('simple_html_dom.php'); 
$html = file_get_html('yoururl'); 
foreach($html->find('div=[data-gamename="1X2"]') as $a){
echo $a->plaintext; 
echo nl2br('\n'); 
} 
?>
```

Any idea where am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 3 problems, first the css is wrong, there's an extra = in there. Second, simple_html_dom is old and doesn't fully support css. For a library that does better I suggest [this one](https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/advanced_html_dom). Third, why do you call your div `$a`? That's confusing.

```
include('advanced_html_dom.php'); 
$html = file_get_html('https://sport.premierbet.com/tz/sport/1/#'); 
foreach($html->find('div[data-gamename="1X2"]') as $div){
  echo $div->plaintext; 
  echo nl2br('\n'); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply pguardiario, the extra = was typing error my bad, I was out of idea let me try to run and see if it will work,

Comment: Thanks a lot man it worked but another challenge rise please go through it if it will be with in your ability see below codes and info i post separately.

Comment: I can't post the code here because they are too long but the idea is i have three DIV which there share attribute unique name of 'data-gamename="1X2"' and each carry its own value, if i just retrieve them normal like the codes above they will be retrieved but without any sort, so what i want is Example
 
`<div class="outcome" data-eventcodeid="88" data-gamename="1X2">2.25</div>` hold the value of 2.25 i want it to be fetched and value to be hold in lets say $game1 then another div like this `<div class="outcome" data-eventcodeid="88" data-gamename="1X2">1.73</div>`

Comment: hold the value of 1.73 i want it to be fetched and value to be hold in lets say $game2 the last one is this `<div class="outcome" data-eventcodeid="88" data-gamename="1X2">1.86</div>` hold the value of 1.86 i want it to be fetched and value to be hold in lets say $game3 Hope you get my point now data-gamename=1X2 it is only what identify them.

Comment: Please go through the two comments above this as a single comment @pguardiario

Comment: you can do `list($game1...) = $html->find('some css')->texts` or use an array (which makes more sense.)